# Archivos de datos en Docker

Tags: sql, sql-server, docker, macos, transact-sql

Estoy estudiando el grado superior de Sistemas  Informáticos y para la asignatura de Bases de datos se usa SQL Server. Mi PC es un MAC por lo que uso Docker para poder hacer las prácticas con SQL.
Me han dado los archivos de datos .mdf y .ldf de una base de datos a la que tengo que hacerle consultas.
He copiado los archivos en el contenedor de datos dentro de la ubicación:
/var/opt/mssql/data/

Seguidamente ejecuté:

```
CREATE DATABASE Example
ON 
(FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/File1.mdf'),
(FILENAME = '/var/opt/mssql/data/File1_log.ldf')
FOR ATTACH;
```

Tengo la base de datos creada en Azure Data Studio pero dentro no hay tablas cuando sí deberia de haberlas.
Qué paso es el que estoy haciendo incorrecto? Realizo ésto porque en Azure Data Studio no doy con la opción 'Attach' que sí tiene SQL Server para añadir los archivos de datos.

Comment: es una extensión, en el "marketplace" busca "SQL Server Import"

Comment: Duda, no te saldría mas fácil  usar una VM con Windows y SQL Server??

Comment: Buenas @OCHOA funcionaba muy lento y me daba demasiados problemas...